# Is there a way for me to show DataSet visualizer in application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I notice when I'm debugging in Visual Studio 2005+ - if I hover a DataSet, DataTable or XML object there is an option for a visualizer. In this case I have a DataSet, so I get the DataSet visualizer which gives me a window with ComboBox to choose which DataTable to view and automatically displays all the contents.

Is there a way for me to pop this window from my actual application? I am creating an administrative application and would like to have a raw view like this available without building it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, but building your own and databinding it to the dataset should be simple enough.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, was just salivating thinking I could do a ShowVisualizerDialog(Dataset ds);

Comment: Probably not without shipping some components of Visual Studio; rolling your own from a DataGridView / ComboBox with a little Databinding should be easy enough though :)